# Sharing violation on path... in subsequent read-write C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, persistence

I'm writing a code that is responsible for persisting and restoring sessions of a game. Everything was quite fine until I performed load and save immidiatelly after it (intentionally), which caused "IOException: Sharing violation on path..." on the console.

The thing is that (to my knowledge and best intentions) I am trying to perform read-writes one after another, not asynchronously, so I don't understand what am I missing. I know that quick save/loads in rapid succession might sound a bit odd, but I'm trying to understand the nature of handles and file locks.

```
public async Task<GameState> LoadSession(string fileName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
                int numRead;
                while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    sb.Append(text);
                }
            }

            GameState state;

            state = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameState>(sb.ToString());
            return state;
        }
```

after which happens:

```
private async Task LoadSession(string fileName)
       {
           var loadedSession = await _sessionHandler.LoadSession(fileName);
           EventSystem.Publish(new OnSessionLoaded() {LoadedSession = loadedSession});
       }
```

and in response to the sent event happens quick save:

```
public async Task SaveSession(string Filename){ 
            var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"{Filename}.sav");
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(serializedObject);

            using var outputFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
            var task = outputFile.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);

            await task;
        }
```

My idea was to wait with saving after the load was completed and "using" disposed of the file handle. The "async" was for not locking a thread/ui/whatever with IO operation.

Comment: My brain died but your save session never seems to close the stream

Comment: isn't that what "using" is supposed to do? [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: Yes but without the braces I’m not sure that code works the way you want it to. Id expect the using too end on the same line and then try the write after

Comment: Ok I will put it into braces for a test, but the repro is Load=>Save=>Error, so the lock has to be caused by Load. And "using" in the save method is in braces.

Comment: Might need to check you aren’t causing a race condition and caring load/save multiple times